# Selling a house inside an estate

Tags: united-states, new-jersey, trusts-and-estates

The XYZ person dies and the will says that all the assets of XYZ goes into a trust. The estate of the XYZ person includes a house. Under what circumstances, if any, can the executor of the XYZ estate sell the house?

Comment: Is there a reason that it would matter if it was sold by the estate rather than the trust?

Comment: @ohwilleke Yes, because of insurance and income tax.  It is my understanding that if the house is owned by an irrevocable trust then it does not qualify for the 250K exclusion.

Comment: If the house was owned by an irrevocable trust at death, then it wouldn't be property in the estate. If it was owned by a natural person or a revocable trust at death, then there is the step up in basis at death rather than the 250K exclusion. *See* 26 U.S.C. § 1014 (step up in basis at death) v. 26 U.S.C. § 121 (exclusion of gain). The 250K exclusion only applies to property sold by people who are still alive. The insurance shouldn't be that big of a consideration.

Comment: @ohwilleke This is my understanding. If a house goes into an irrevocable trust for person X, and then 5 years later person X sells the house (because he wants to move) person X does not get the 250K exclusion. Am I right about that?

Comment: You are right about that, although the tax would only be on appreciation from date of death to the sale. But if it went into the trust and was sold immediately by the trust, v. being sold by the estate before the proceeds went into the trust, there would be no difference. The estate wouldn't get the $250K exclusion either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In accordance with the terms of the trust deed

Those terms of the will that are related to the trust will become the trust deed in the absence of one included for the purpose.

The trustee(s) can administer the trust on behalf of the beneficiaries in accordance with the terms. Unless the deed expressly prohibits the sale (either in total or subject to conditions) the trustee(s) can do what they think proper.

Comment: My question is can the executor of the will sell the home? That is, can it be sold before it goes into trust.

Comment: Immediately the testator dies a testimonial trust comes into existence containing all assets that are part of the estate - so no.

Comment: so are you telling me that the executor could not sell the house?

Comment: No. I’m telling you what I told you.